# Efficiently matching documents based on another document in the same collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to find documents using a `$match` that depends on the values found in exactly one other document in the same collection. A hard constraint is that I only have the `_id` of that document to start with.

Solving this in two queries is straightforward. The first query gets the whole document corresponding to the `_id`:

```js
db.Collection.findOne({_id: ObjectId("62ceb83beb15796caa71514c")})
```

The second query uses the values in the document returned by the above query to match other documents. For example:

```js
db.Collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { timestamp: { $lt: Long("1657714680") } },
        { timestamp: Long("1657714680"), _id: { $lt: ObjectId("62ceb83beb15796caa71514c") } }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $sort: { timestamp: -1, _id: -1 } },
  { $limit: 10 },
])
```

But it would be nice to do this in one query. For example:

```js
db.Collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: ObjectId("62ceb83beb15796caa71514c") } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Collection",
      as: "a",
      let: { ts: "$timestamp" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $or: [
                {$lt: ["$timestamp", "$$ts"]},
                {
                  $and: [
                    {timestamp: "$$ts"},
                    {$lt: ["$_id", ObjectId("62ceb83beb15796caa71514c")]}
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        { $sort: { timestamp: -1, _id: -1 } },
        { $limit: 1 }
      ]
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$a" },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$a" } }
])
```

However, this approach with `$lookup` and `$expr` doesn't make good use of the index (`{ timestamp: -1, _id: -1 }`) because the condition is too complex. I'm on MongoDB 4.4, which has limited support for index use with `$expr`. But support on the latest version, 7.0, is still insufficient (it actually uses the index on 7.0, but it's slow because the `totalDocsExamined` is still high, presumably due to the use of multiple field paths in the condition).

[Here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/operator/query/expr/#behavior) are the constraints on index use with `$expr` in 4.4. [Here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/operator/query/expr/#behavior) are the constraints in 7.0.

Here is the `explain('executionStats')` output for the single query on 7.0:

```
{
  explainVersion: '1',
  stages: [
    {
      '$cursor': {
        queryPlanner: {
          namespace: 'tyson_nottingham_data.Collection',
          indexFilterSet: false,
          parsedQuery: { _id: { '$eq': ObjectId("62ceb83beb15796caa71514c") } },
          queryHash: '0BA3081B',
          planCacheKey: 'EFC2BC0A',
          maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached: false,
          maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached: false,
          maxScansToExplodeReached: false,
          winningPlan: {
            stage: 'PROJECTION_SIMPLE',
            transformBy: { timestamp: 1, _id: 0 },
            inputStage: { stage: 'IDHACK' }
          },
          rejectedPlans: []
        },
        executionStats: {
          executionSuccess: true,
          nReturned: 1,
          executionTimeMillis: 1558,
          totalKeysExamined: 1,
          totalDocsExamined: 1,
          executionStages: {
            stage: 'PROJECTION_SIMPLE',
            nReturned: 1,
            executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
            works: 2,
            advanced: 1,
            needTime: 0,
            needYield: 0,
            saveState: 1,
            restoreState: 1,
            isEOF: 1,
            transformBy: { timestamp: 1, _id: 0 },
            inputStage: {
              stage: 'IDHACK',
              nReturned: 1,
              executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
              works: 2,
              advanced: 1,
              needTime: 0,
              needYield: 0,
              saveState: 1,
              restoreState: 1,
              isEOF: 1,
              keysExamined: 1,
              docsExamined: 1
            }
          }
        }
      },
      nReturned: Long("1"),
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: Long("0")
    },
    {
      '$lookup': {
        from: 'Collection',
        as: 'a',
        let: { ts: '$timestamp' },
        pipeline: [
          {
            '$match': {
              '$expr': {
                '$or': [
                  { '$lt': [ '$timestamp', '$$ts' ] },
                  { 
                    '$and': [
                      { timestamp: '$$ts' },
                      { 
                        '$lt': [
                          '$_id',
                          ObjectId("62ceb83beb15796caa71514c")
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          { '$sort': { timestamp: -1, _id: -1 } },
          { '$limit': 10 }
        ],
        unwinding: { preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false }
      },
      totalDocsExamined: Long("1171641"),
      totalKeysExamined: Long("1171641"),
      collectionScans: Long("0"),
      indexesUsed: [ 'timestamp_-1__id_-1' ],
      nReturned: Long("10"),
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: Long("1558")
    },
    { 
      '$replaceRoot': { newRoot: '$a' },
      nReturned: Long("10"),
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: Long("1558")
    }
  ],
  serverInfo: {
    host: 'b104a7d764ff',
    port: 27017,
    version: '7.0.0',
    gitVersion: '37d84072b5c5b9fd723db5fa133fb202ad2317f1'
  },
  serverParameters: {
    internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS: 0,
    internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes: 104857600,
    internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryFrameworkControl: 'trySbeEngine'
  },
  command: {
    aggregate: 'Collection',
    pipeline: [
      { '$match': { _id: ObjectId("62ceb83beb15796caa71514c") } },
      { 
        '$lookup': {
          from: 'Collection',
          as: 'a',
          let: { ts: '$timestamp' },
          pipeline: [
            { 
              '$match': {
                '$expr': {
                  '$or': [
                    { '$lt': [ '$timestamp', '$$ts' ] },
                    { 
                      '$and': [
                        { timestamp: '$$ts' },
                        { 
                          '$lt': [
                            '$_id',
                            ObjectId("62ceb83beb15796caa71514c")
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            { '$sort': { timestamp: -1, _id: -1 } },
            { '$limit': 10 }
          ]
        }
      },
      { '$unwind': '$a' },
      { '$replaceRoot': { newRoot: '$a' } }
    ],
    cursor: {},
    '$db': 'tyson_nottingham_data'
  },
  ok: 1
}
```

Is there an alternative approach that can accomplish this efficiently in a single query, with the constraint that I only have the `_id` of the document of interest to start with? Solutions that work for MongoDB versions other than 4.4 are acceptable.

Comment: Are you okay with using 7.0, or is 4.4 a hard constraint? What's the index that you're trying to use with the $lookup? Can you share the `"executionStats"` verbosity `explain` output?

Comment: 7.0 is acceptable. Index is `{ timestamp: -1, _id: -1 }`. Added `explain` output to question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done with one query. If you need to use data in the first document then you have to read the first document. And then if you want to find additional documents based off data in the first then that's a whole different operation. One alternative approach that could be more efficient is to use a combination of aggregation and the $out stage to materialize results into a temporary collection.

```
// Step 1: Join the collection with itself using $lookup
db.Collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { _id: ObjectId("62ceb83beb15796caa71514c") }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Collection",
      localField: "timestamp",
      foreignField: "timestamp",
      as: "related_docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$related_docs"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { "related_docs.timestamp": { $lt: Long("1657714680") } },
        {
          $and: [
            { "related_docs.timestamp": Long("1657714680") },
            { "related_docs._id": { $lt: ObjectId("62ceb83beb15796caa71514c") } }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  // Step 2: Save intermediate results into a temporary collection
  {
    $merge: "temp_results"
  }
]);

// Step 3: Perform additional aggregation on the temporary collection
db.temp_results.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: { "related_docs.timestamp": -1, "related_docs._id": -1 }
  },
  {
    $limit: 10
  },
  // Optionally, project or reshape the output as needed
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$related_docs._id",
      timestamp: "$related_docs.timestamp",
      // Add other fields as needed
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your single query solution is correct.
However, in $match you used

```
                     '$and': [
                        { timestamp: '$$ts' },
```

Which is incorrect in $expr context.
If you replace it with {$eq: ["$timestamp", "$$ts"]} it should work.

I created a reproduction and it seems to use correct indexes and limited merge sort to answer the predicate pretty efficiently.

My pipeline:

```
[
  {$match: {
    a: 6,
    b: 4,
  }},
  {$lookup: {
    from: "test",
    let: {localA: "$a", localB: "$b"},
    pipeline: [
      {$match: {$expr: {$or: [
        {$lt: ["$a", "$$localA"]},
        {$and: [
          {$eq: ["$a", "$$localA"]},
          {$lt: ["$b", "$$localB"]}
        ]}
      ]}}},
      {$sort: {a: -1, b: -1}},
      {$limit: 1}
    ],
    as: "result"
}
```

Explain output where you can see that only one document was fetched:

```
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": "test",
        "as": "result",
        "let": { "localA": "$a", "localB": "$b" },
        "pipeline": [<...>]
      },
      "totalDocsExamined": 1,
      "totalKeysExamined": 2,
      "collectionScans": 0,
      "indexesUsed": ["a_1_b_1"],
      "nReturned": 1,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 1
    }
```